# Jquery live not firing on success

Tags: jquery, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm having issues with jquery live firing on ajax success. Here is my link_to function.

```
<%= link_to image_tag("cross.png"), patient_recurrence_detail_path(params[:id],f.object.id), :remote => true, :class => 'delete_recurrence_detail', :method => :delete, :confirm=>'Are you sure you?' %>
```

The method it calls is this

```
def destroy
  @recurrence_detail = RecurrenceDetail.find(params[:id])
  @recurrence_detail.destroy
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to patient_path(params[:patient_id]) }
    format.js { render :nothing => true }
  end
end
```

Lastly, I have a jquery live function attached to the link created. (I've used .bind() here to no avail)

```
$('a[data-method="delete"]').live("ajax:success", function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
   $(this).parents('div.fields').remove();
});
```

I notice in my network traffic I am receiving a status of OK for the delete before, so I am a bit puzzled as to why the live function is not being called. Note: I've also tried using .bind() as well. I do have the jquery-rails gem.

Update: I've tried using .ajaxSuccess() and updated my gem, but still no success. Do I need to add something to my respond_to for ajax?

Comment: could be a syntax problem using colon in event name, come to think of it if ajax:before isn't a custom event it is definitely an issue

Comment: Sorry, edited the post. I meant to have ajax:success there.

Comment: ajasSuccess is a method  http://api.jquery.com/ajaxSuccess/ I've never seen it in a bind, safer to use the method syntax

Comment: really can't see enough of what you are doing to help, might start a thread with more focus on ajax client side js code

Comment: What is the version of your `jquery-rails`?

Comment: My version is jquery-rails (1.0.19, 1.0.14)

Answer (score 1):

minimalistic answer, i know, but maybe try the more current [api.jquery.com/on](http://api.jquery.com/on)?

edit: i think the gem just got bumped to jquery 1.7.1 about a month ago...

Answer (score 0):

Until now, I didn't know that was even possible! Then I learned from the [docs](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax_Events) that Ajax events are broadcast to all DOM elements.

As per the documentation, you should be binding to `ajaxSuccess`, not "ajax:success".

Comment: $('a[data-method="delete"]').bind("ajaxSuccess",... but no success. So strange.

Comment: It should work, see [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/RMDVq/3/). Are you sure the ajax request is actually being fired (use Firebug console)? Otherwise, ajaxSuccess will never fire.

Comment: Yeah, it should. I must have something quirky going on. I ended up having the js response remove the field from the DOM, but thank you for your help, bfavaretto.